# iMacro, click on <a> manually executes javascript, but does not work in iMacro

Tags: imacros

The `<a>` does not have href, on click of `<a>` 2 javascript functions are executed. I need to automated executing the 2 javascript functions.  `page_xx` changes on every load, also in the function, `vars()` is 4 to 6 variables which are loaded dynamically and again change each time so can't run this manually.

```
<div>
  <span>
    <a class="focus next_page page_xx" onclick="runfunc(vars());openWin(vars())"></a>
  </span>
</div>
```

First I tried a basic click on the `<a>`

```
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=a ATTR=CLASS:focus
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=a ATTR=CLASS:next_page
```

neither worked, there was no errors but they did not run the js functions. 
I then tried event command, but got error saying my version of iMacros does not support.

I tried to then execute the functions, but I am having no luck in getting anywhere near the code to do that.

How could I executre the 2 functions, either by clicking the `<a>` or executing the functions without tne click?

iMacros version 10.0.2.1450
Firefox latest version.

Comment: Your OP is a bit "annoying" to read and not easy to understand, full of Typos (starting with "iMacros" that you spell in 3 different ways but each time with 2 or 3 Typos in just one single Word) + missing Words... - Your "simply clicking" should work and it's perfectly fine to use its Class to tag that Link but iMacros needs the full Class, "there was no error[s]" because you probably use '!ERRORIGNORE'......- Or if it is Dynamic, then you need to apply one of the Techniques to deal with Dynamic Elements: 'Wildcard(s)' and/or 'Extraction' and/or 'Relative Positioning'...

Comment: Chill out mate.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add wild card to end of class as iMacros matches all text.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=a ATTR=CLASS:focus*
```

Comment: Yep, very good...!, exactly what I meant with "but iMacros needs the full Class" + "[use] Wildcard(s)"...

Answer (score 0):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=a ATTR=CLASS:"focus next_page page_xx"
```

This is the complete solution.

Comment: Nope..., this one won't work, as #OP mentioned that "page_xx" keeps changing..., the "page_xx" part at least needs to be replaced by "page_*" (=> with a Wildcard for the changing part)...